# Herencia en Java - Al llamar a un constructor se salta el contenido de este mismo y va a otro?

Tags: java, java-8

No entiendo porque en el constructor de C al acabar de llamar al constructor de A con un parámetro, este en vez imprimir por pantalla "Soy el constructor C" va directamente a instanciar un objeto de B y accede a su constructor, en vez de decir "Soy el contructor C" primero antes que "Soy el contructor B". No entiendo por qué?

```
class A {
    public A ( ) {  System.out.println(" Soy el constructor A");    }
    public A (int a) { 
        System.out.println(" Soy el constructor A " + a);
    }
}

class B {
    public B ( ) {  System.out.println(" Soy el constructor B");    }
    /*public B (int b) { 
        System.out.println(" Soy el constructor B " + b);
    }*/
}

class C extends A {
    public C ( ) {
        super(1);
        System.out.println(" Soy el constructor C");
    }
    B ob= new B();
}

public class ex6b_2 {
    public static void main ( String args[] ) {
        C oc= new C();
    }
}
```

[image: Este es el resultado al ejecutar el programa]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si no recuerdo mal, tiene que ver con el orden en que java o otros lenguajes leen la información y la guardan.

En función de esto ejecutan el código, y aunque a veces parezca de mentira, ejecutan el código de una manera imprevista.

Puedes probar 2 cosas.
La primera es cambiar el orden

```
class A {
    public A ( ) {  System.out.println(" Soy el constructor A");    }
    public A (int a) { 
        System.out.println(" Soy el constructor A " + a);
    }
}



class C extends A {
    public C ( ) {
        super(1);
        System.out.println(" Soy el constructor C");
    }
    B ob= new B();
}
 class B {
    public B ( ) {  System.out.println(" Soy el constructor B");    }
    /*public B (int b) { 
        System.out.println(" Soy el constructor B " + b);
    }*/
}
public class ex6b_2 {
    public static void main ( String args[] ) {
        C oc= new C();
    }
}
```

Creo que te dará el mismo resultado.
La segunda forma.

```
  class C extends A {
        public C ( ) {
            super(1);
            System.out.println(" Soy el constructor C");
            B ob = new B(); // o creando un método para el
        }

    }
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: De la primera forma que has dicho no ha funcionado, al final la solucion ha sido la segundo que has propuesto, la de poner la instanciacion de un objeto de la clase B  dejabo de la impresión de "soy el contructor C"!
Aprecio mucho la ayuda compañero!

Comment: Me alegro de haber ayudado.

Comment: "ejecutan el código de una manera imprevista." Esto no es correcto. Para aclarar porque actua así, ver la otra respuesta, pero de ningún modo un compilador o interprete ejecuta el código de manera imprevista o aleatoria.

Comment: "ejecutan el código de una manera imprevista." , quiero decir que crees que se van a desarrollar en, orden pero hasta que no te tropiezas con esto, no sabes el orden en que java, en esto caso carga la información.

Comment: En todo caso es desconocimiento del programador de como funciona el lenguaje y el compilador/intereprete. En la respuesta de jachguate puedes ver por qué funciona así

Answer (score 2):

La creación del objeto `ob`, aunque es parte de la construcción del objeto, no está escrita dentro de tu constructor, sino que es un *campo* con un valor *default* que también se crea durante el proceso de construcción de tu instancia.

Solo para tener mayor claridad, otra forma de escribir la clase `C` sería esta:

```
class C extends A {
    public B ob = new B();

    public C ( ) {
        super(1);
        System.out.println(" Soy el constructor C");
    }
}
```

Que produce exactamente el mismo resultado en todos los sentidos. La representación en memoria de los objetos es la misma y la salida producida por el programa también, simplemente queda claro que `new B()` no es una parte de código explicitamente escrita en el constructor.

Y ocurre que en Java, todos los *campos* que están declarados en una clase, son creados cuándo se termina de construir la parte del objeto que se ha heredado y antes que se ejecute la primera línea del constructor, dado que este ya tiene acceso a los valores de estos campos.

Para probar esto, he extendido un poco tu ejemplo, creando una clase `PreA` que ahora es ancestro de `A` y un par de clases auxiliares, de esta forma puedes observar el orden en el que se van creando los objetos en memoria a medida que se construye la instancia de `C`:

```
public class So287592 {
    public static void main ( String args[] ) {
        C oc= new C();
    }
}

class PreA {
  public PreA() { System.out.println(" Soy el constructor PreA"); }

}
class A extends PreA {
    public B1 ob1 = new B1();
    public A ( ) {  System.out.println(" Soy el constructor A");    }
    public A (int a) { 
        System.out.println(" Soy el constructor A " + a);
    }
}

class B {
    public B ( ) {  System.out.println(" Soy el constructor B");    }
}

class B1 {
    public B1 ( ) {  System.out.println(" Soy el constructor B1");    }
}

class C extends A {
    public B ob = new B();
    public C ( ) {
        super(1);
        System.out.println(" Soy el constructor C");
    }
}
```

Esto produce la siguiente salida:

```
 Soy el constructor PreA
 Soy el constructor B1
 Soy el constructor A 1
 Soy el constructor B
 Soy el constructor C
```

Como ves, primero se ejecuta el constructor de `PreA`, luego, se crean los campos declarados en `A` y dado que `ob1` tiene como *default* una nueva instancia de `B1`, se invoca en constructor de esta clase, antes de ejecutar el código del constructor de `A`.

Luego, se ejecuta el código del constructor de `A`, y cuando se termina de construir esta parte del objeto, se crean los campos declarados en `C`. Esto implica, de manera análoga, la creación del objeto `ob`, por lo que se invoca al constructor de `B`.

Finalmente, se ejecuta el código específico del constructor de `C`, que ya tiene acceso a todos los campos de la clase, incluidas las instancias creadas para los miembros `ob` y `ob1`